# Avoiding "keep me signed in" from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

Our consultant normally works on our customers' computers, so we consider them as "public computers". Thus, our consultants have been instructed to never use any "Keep me signed in"-features, such as when they connect to Office 365.

Here's the problem:
We use Visual Studio Team Services, our company's subscription, for storing source code. As with Office 365, the consultants are instructed to not check "Keep me signed in" when they connect to Visual Studio Team Services from VS2012.

However, it seems as if Visual Studio caches the credentials, even if "Keep me signed in" is not checked. Next time VS is started, it connects automatically to our VS Team Services environment. This has the effect that our customer can (at least theoretically) login to the consultant's computer and access our Visual Studio Online environment, with access to all our code that is stored there (which includes other customers' code). To me, this seems like a big security flaw.

So, am I missing something? Is there anyway to avoid Visual Studio from caching the credentials when access Visual Studio Team Services?

Note:
The only way for us to make VS2012 "forget" the credentials is to clear the cache in IE, and we can't expect our consultants to do this each time they leave their computer.
I have seen many articles that the credentials are stored in Windows Credential Manager, but that is not the case for us - there are no credentials there.

Thanks,
Fredrik

Answer (score 2):

If you are that concerned with security then you should have your consultants use their own computers when onsite.

Failing that you can instruct them to "logout" of Visual Studio before leaving their machine.